# How to prevent reload with onclick without "#"?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I wish to put some instructions with a link - onclick calling a script that display a simple alert box. If I did like this...

```
<label for="arquivo">Máximo de 1MB, observe os <a href="" onclick="ajudaUpload();">tipos permitidos</a>.</label>
```

the page is reloaded even with a return false, and if I did like this...

```
<label for="arquivo">Máximo de 1MB, observe os <a href="#" onclick="ajudaUpload();">tipos permitidos</a>.</label>
```

with the "#" symbol, the page is scrolled to the top and "#" is added to query string. Is there a third way to do it without reloading, scrolling and garbage?

Comment: @Prisoner it's necessary for usability, like keyboard navigation and the default link styling

Comment: Chances are, you shouldn't be using the `onclick` attribute in the first place.

Comment: @Izkata no you can just use a `<button>` and the styling argument is ridiculous, how hard is it to create a css class with link styles?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Return false after the call:

```
<a href="" onclick="ajudaUpload();return false;">tipos permitidos</a>
```

Or if your function returns false then you can return the result of the function:

```
<a href="" onclick="return ajudaUpload();">tipos permitidos</a>
```

It's not enough to just return false in the function, you need to actually return false from the click handler.

Comment: I did a test in Safari and works like the first line. Also, is not needed the return false in the function. It seams the browser ignore the returning value and uses only what is inside the onclick.

Comment: Edit: I did a test again with the second line and it works too, I just forget the return before the call...

Comment: Yes, it's important that the onclick event ultimately returns false. If only the function returns false then the expression will just be evaluated and the click event won't return anything.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.preventDefault()` method, or return false, or remove the HREF tag all together. Either should work just fine.

Vc nao deviar estar usando `onclick` dessa forma pra comecar. Ja eh bem antigo e nao se usa assim mais.

Comment: @Christian: No, it's a standard function, though a shim is needed for IE8.

Comment: Why the down vote?
http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation

Comment: +1 This is a standard DOM API method of the event object. There's no reason to down vote it.

Comment: Eu sou antigo hahaha! I'm old man... put an example how to replace href, but the link must follow the text flow, a simple button doesn't fit.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="" onclick="return ajudaUpload()">tipos permitidos</a>
```

and then return false in your function:

```
function ajudaUpload()
{
  ...
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Why even bother dealing with the `return` value of the function call? Just `return false;` after the function call and it will do the same thing, without creating separation

Comment: Well that'll do the same in this case, but you might want to return true if some conditions are met.

Comment: @Samurai Of course, it just seemed straightforward that it would only be `false`, but it could very well need to be either true or false

Comment: Sorry, in fact it works, I did the test wrong. And I'd put +1 for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0);" onclick="ajudaUpload();">
```

Even I was stuck on a similar problem. I wanted to use onclick function but the page would reload, which I didn't want. I tried href = "javascript:void(0);" and it worked.

Comment: Interesting! Not sure if is regular the use of javascript as a reference, but there is a chance of onclick do not return Boolean if it crashes for some reason, and in this case, the reload is executed. This hack might prevent from to execute the reload, it worth to try.

Comment: accepted answer did not work 4 me - would still reload, this one did, wonder why.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple way to do this is just add '?' (questionmark) :)

F.e.

```
<a href="#?">Moiz Travadi</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost any element suports onclick events, so you can use a b tag, or a button tag, even an span tag. Then you can style it to look just like a link (a tag), or any other way you want. For example:

```
<label for="arquivo">Máximo de 1MB, observe os <b onclick="ajudaUpload();">tipos permitidos</b>.</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally when we click a Button on our page, button performs ts actions and the page gets reloaded to its original state. To do not refresh the page we add event.preventDefault(); at the end of our JavaScript function.

```
<button id="myBtn">Try it​</button> 
<p id="demo">
</p> 
<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script> ​<br/>
```

Another code can be:

```
<button id="myBtn" onclick="test()">Try it​</button>
<p id="demo"> 
</p>
<script>
function test(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
    event.preventDefault();
}
</script> ​​<br/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove your herf and give id for your tag. Then by using id you can show your alert. ('#id').click(function (){alert(message); return false;
});