# load different div with different conten and not reload the page?

Tags: html, href, reload

I have the following code to load different div with different content by clicking on a link. My question is how can I write so that not reload the page every time I click on a link.

```
#content > div {
    display: none;
}
#content > div:target {
    display: block;
}
<a href="#div1">Div one</a>
<a href="#div2">Div two</a>
<a href="#div3">Div three</a>
<a href="#div4">Div four</a>

<div id="content">
    <div id="div1">This is div one</div>
    <div id="div2">This is div two</div>
    <div id="div3">This is div three</div>
    <div id="div4">This is div four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `document.location.hash` to your anchor. For example for div1 link :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.location.hash='#div1'; return false;">Div one</a>
```

EDIT> since previous code keeps reloading the page. the following approach (inspired from what other answer suggests) seems to fit :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#div1').show().siblings().hide();return false;">Div one</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5XqyX/

Comment: Can I do this without using javascript?

Comment: Actually I do not think so.

Comment: my bad, add `return false;` at the end of the onclick content. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680436/how-to-prevent-reload-with-onclick-without

Comment: Are you sure, the page still reload? Sorry!

Comment: Hmmm I might not having understood your real problem then. What exactly do witness when you say the page "reload" ?

Comment: If you like, please click on the link below.
And click on "Privatperson" and "Företag" under the title "Kontaktuppgifter / Registrera dig som kund"
http://s10.se/agv/kopia.php

Comment: I'd pleased to help but I am behind a filtered proxy that won't let me go. If you keep have problems there, I suggest you try Gareth or Patrick solutions. using a bit (not much) of javascript to show/hide the desired div

Comment: try this (basically the implementation of others answer :S ) : http://jsfiddle.net/5XqyX/

Answer (score 1):

you can add onclick event to the link tag like , then in the js function clickFun() you can do some logic to display and hide specific div area.

Comment: How exactly do I do that?

Comment: easy way to do that is to use jquery or add document.getElementById("divid").style.display="none" into function when click link, then show the one document.getElementById("elementId").style.display="block".

Answer (score 1):

You could either use jquery to hide 3 of the divs and show the other one (if they aren't too big to render) or use bootstrap tabs or similar if they are basically whole pages you want to tab between

Comment: Can I do this without using javascript?