# HTML page keeps reloading after click event

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a small website, which keeps reloading after a click event. How can I prevent this?

PS: I'm only allowed to use pure JS.

**HTML**

Cookie Clicker

```
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Points: </h1>
        <span id="score"></span>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <a href="" onclick="addPoints(1)">
                <img src="assets/graphics/Friis.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="assets/scripts/cookieClicker.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var points = 0,
    score = document.getElementById("score");

function addPoints(increase) {
    console.log('hit');
    points += increase;

    score.innerHTML = '' + points;
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent reload with onclick without "#"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680436/how-to-prevent-reload-with-onclick-without)

Comment: Change `href` to `href="javascript:;"` or pass the `event` and call `preventDefault()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify only your html and it works:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addPoints(1)">
```

Some people make this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addPoints(1)">
```

But this is an anchor that scrolls your page to top. If you need to make by javascript, search about `event preventDefault`.

### EDIT

Read about `void` javascript function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

It's good to understand behaviour.

Comment: Great solution better than mine! I didn't think of that

Answer (score 3):

update your code to:

```
<a href="" onclick="addPoints(1);return false">
```

or

```
<a href="" onclick="return addPoints(1)">
```

and let your function addPoints return false. Upside of this is that you can actually let the href link to a page in case addPoints reaches a certain level for instance. If addPoints returns true the link will take the user to that page, return false will keep the user on the current page.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using onClick you can just change the href to run the function.
For example:

```
<a href="javascript:addPoints(1);">
```

Answer (score 1):

that happens because you code contain

```
   <a href="" onclick="addPoints(1)"> // These Can Reload Same Page
   <a href="#" onclick="addPoints(1)"> // Modify upper code to these code
```