# Save Data Without Refreshing The Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have a view that refresh the time of a model in database whenever it's called.

```
def data(request):
    new = Data.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if new:
        new.update(timestamp=timezone.now())
```

This view is related to the URL,

```
url(r'^data/$', views.data, name='data')
```

So, how can I call this view & update the time in database when user click a URL or a button without refreshing the page?

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate,  e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680436/how-to-prevent-reload-with-onclick-without .  The key is for onclick to return false.

Comment: @mikep Sir, that code is refreshing the page. Also I need to put the `href="something"` redirecting to that view

Answer (score 0):

Proceeding from the comments:

In the html:

```
<button type="button" id="someid" onclick="idclick()">Click me</button>
```

In the javascript:

```
function idclick() {
    ....
    return false;
}
```